# Is there a version of __file__ that when used in a function, will get the name of the file that uses the library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, goto

So, as a joke I wrote a version of goto for python that I wanted to use as a library. The function I wrote for it is as follows.

```
def goto(loc):
  exec(open(__file__).read().split("# "+str(loc))[1],globals())
  quit()
```

This works for cases where it is in the file where goto is used, such as this:

```
def goto(loc):
  exec(open(__file__).read().split("# "+str(loc))[1],globals())
  quit()


# hi
print("test")
goto("hi")
```

However, if I import goto in another file, it doesn't work as

```
__file__
```

will always return the file with the function in it, not the one it is used in. Is there an equivalent of file that will allow me to import a file with the goto function in it and have it work?

Comment: Couldn't be bothered to post an answer, but yes - you have to dig around in the call stack, start looking in  `inspect.currentframe().f_back`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can if you inspect the call stack:

```
import inspect

def goto():
    try:
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        print(frame.f_back.f_globals['__file__'])
    finally:
        # break reference cycles
        # https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack
        del frame

goto()
```

Note that the call stack is actually python implementation dependent -- So for some python interpreters, this might not actually work...

Of course, I've also shown you how to get the caller's globals (`locals` can be found via `frame.f_back.f_locals` for all of your `exec`ing needs).

Also note that [it looks like you can implement a jump command](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects) by writing to the frame's `f_lineno` -- which might be a better way to implement your `goto`.  I've never done this though so I can't really advise you on how to actually code it up :-)